# Prevent Image stretch

Tags: android, android-imageview

I just created a custom list view. In my custom cell layout I just put a background image to relative layout but images are stretched. Should I create a new image with low density and put it in ldpi folder?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_detail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:src="@drawable/cell_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.45"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_sec_area_insepected_textview"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/select_trip_breakline2"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/crosshair_ui_table_cell_breakline_row" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@null"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/circuleforlistview"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a nicely made [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: solved put image in hdpi drawable thanks to help me an i am also try to used ninepatch